# Vaadin 14 drop position in a DIV if you use DragSource and DropTarget pair

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, location, vaadin, drop

Any of you have experiences with DragSource/DropTarget pair in Vaadin 14? Within the grid the drop target ensures the drop location but I have not find any solution how I can get the drop position in a DIV if it is defined as a DropTarget.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're looking for this missing feature: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/6796